# KeyError: 'features'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyword

I was trying to train the model, but I getting the below error. Can some one please help me identify why I am getting this error and how can I get this fixed?
Following is a part of the code::

```
with gzip.open('mfcc_feat.pkl', 'rb') as ifp:
file = pickle.load(ifp)
print(file.head())
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Downloads\\emotion_values.csv')
file = file.merge(df, on='Name', how='outer')
print(file.head())
print(file['features'][10].shape)
```

The error i am getting is::

```
print(file['features'][10].shape)
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
KeyError: 'features'
```

Comment: Are you sure the `key`,  `file['feat']` exists?

Comment: sorry, i have edited the correct form

Comment: Great, but the question remains, Are you sure the `key`, `file['features']` exists?

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the header names also. It would be more helpful.

Comment: check if `'features'` has preceding or succeeding spaces , you can `print(df.columns)` to see that. If yes do `df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()` and then carry on with your codes.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i completely forgot to insert the features column. thank you for all your suggestions